# insert into a table with values from another one

Tags: sql, db2

I have 2 tables, `product`, `client`

I wanna insert in my product table rows according to the number of rows of my client table :

```
INSERT INTO product (
    id,
    NAME,
    client_id
)
VALUES (
    productSequence.nextval,
    'myProd',
    SELECT client_id FROM client
);
```

This query is wrong, cause `select client_id from client` returns more than one row!

I can't find how to do that

Comment: Where are you getting productSequence.nextval from?

Comment: As I use db2 database, I have a sequence for each table to generate the ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `SELECT` statement instead of `VALUES`, this will produce 1 row for every client in the `client` table so if you have 3 records in `client` you will have 3 inserted records in `product`

```
insert into product(id, name, client_id) 
select productSequence.nextval, 'myProd', client_id from client
```

If `id` is an `IDENTITY` column (database provides the values) in table `product` it should not be provided at all in your statement so then it would be:

```
insert into product(name, client_id) 
select 'myProd', client_id from client
```

Comment: insert into product(id, name, client_id) 
select productSequence.nextval, 'myProd', client_id from client worked for me :)
thanks a lot

Comment: @junior - Glad to help. Please consider marking an answer once the 15 minute grace period has expired using the check-mark on the left side of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where productSequence.nextval is coming from.
But basically it is an INSERT-SELECT statement like below:

```
INSERT INTO product
 SELECT productSequence.nextval
       ,'myProd'
       ,client_id
  FROM client
;
```

tell me where the column productSequence.nextval is coming from and i'll update my statement

Comment: I use the db2 database, for each table I have a sequence to generate the id. productSequence is the sequence I use for my product table.